# Blazor .NET Show loading spinner on UI while doing a heavy query in background

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have following code where i fetch results from SQL server. These are razor pages, blazor framework .Net

```
<button @onclick="Filter">Filter</button>

@{

async Task Filter() {
    await FetchFromDb();
}
```

This query runs for 18 seconds. So i want to show loading spinner. In blazor, you can use a predefined div with spinner class to do this.

```
<div class="spinner"> </div>
```

I want to use this div like following

```
@(IsLoading) {
<div class="spinner"></div>
} else {

show results from query
}
```

For which i need to change the Filter function as follows

```
async Task Filter() {
    IsLoading = true;
    await FetchFromDb();
    IsLoading = false;
}
```

But I figured, that the whole process of changing IsLoading=true and Isloading=false is done in one go and i don't see a spinner.

Is there a way to change IsLoading=true, while Filter function is getting results from Db in await FetchFromDb();
?

```
@(IsLoading) {
<div class="spinner"></div>
} else {

show results from query
}


async Task Filter() {
    IsLoading = true;
    await FetchFromDb();
    IsLoading = false;
}
```

But this doesn't work. IsLoading doesn't get updated on changing IsLoading=True.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like:

```
async Task Filter() {
    IsLoading = true;
    await FetchFromDb();
    IsLoading = false;
}
```

isn't really an async code block.

You should be able to do this and it works:

```
async Task Filter() 
{
    IsLoading = true;
    await Task.Delay(1);
    await FetchFromDb();
    IsLoading = false;
}
```

On the assumption that `Filter` is being called from a UI event such as a button press this is what happens.

The `Task.Delay` yields control back to the UI event handler.  It (the UI event handler) calls `StateHasChanged` and yields awaiting `Filter`. The Renderer gets processor time to service its render queue and runs the component render fragment and render the component

I'm assuming `await FetchFromDb();` is a call into a database.  Either `FetchFromDb` wraps a `Task` around a synchronous database call or you're using a database, such as SQLite, that does the same thing internally with it's exposed async library.

Comment: How about await Task.Yield()  ? instaed of Task.Delay, seems more readable ?, curios to see which would be quicker, i hear Task.Yield can cause a memory exception, what do you know ?

Comment: @fuzzybear - I used to use Yield, but changed over after some enquiries on the topic with MS (prompted by one of these conversations with Henk and Enet a year or so ago).   Stephen is an expert on the topic, and his answer to Ionix is the same as the advice I received.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I'm assuming a UI event is triggering the process.  I've added that assumption to the answer as the OP didn't actually say so.  For anyone interested this is the ComponentBase UI event hander code - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/99ff5e888c71898037a6a51bb3e7eb0aed88194c/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs#L298

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I've clarified *It* as I can see the reason for confusion.  I think I will write a Question/Answer to cover the topic and thus have something to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below component.

Demo: https://demos.getblazorbootstrap.com/preload

```html
@code {
    [Inject] protected PreloadService PreloadService { get; set; }

    private void GetEmployees()
    {
        try
        {
            PreloadService.Show();

            // TODO: call the service/api to get the employees
        }
        catch
        {
            // handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            PreloadService.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```